# TensorBoard without callbacks for Keras docker image in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-s3, keras, tensorboard, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to add TensorBoard functionality to this SageMaker example: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/hyperparameter_tuning/keras_bring_your_own/hpo_bring_your_own_keras_container.ipynb

The issue is that SageMaker's `Estimator.fit()` [does not seem to support Keras models compiled with callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486118/early-stopping-and-callbacks-with-keras-when-using-sagemaker).

Now from [this git issue post](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/208) it was described that what I need to do for TensorBoard functionality is,

> "You need your code inside the container to save checkpoints to S3,
>   and you need to periodically sync your local Tensorboard log directory
>   with your S3 checkpoints."

So to sum it all up, to enable TensorBoard in SageMaker with this custom Keras docker image, it looks like I need a way of periodically uploading a file to an S3 bucket during training without using callbacks. Is this possible to do? I was considering trying to shove this code into a custom loss function, but I'm not sure if this would be the way to go about it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The latest SageMaker TF images support [a new training format](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst) that isn't as restrictive as the old one - would that help? Also not sure if this would be of any use, but SageMaker did recently announce [Early Stopping support for hyperparameter tuning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-early-stopping.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes the script mode is very useful now. I managed to get the basic tensorboard callback working and then add a lambda callback for syncing events files with s3 as well in order to use my custom container.

Comment: @Austin post your result, how did you use lambda callback